# cURL: handle response: line-based text data

Tags: php, curl, response

I'm using cURL to send a request to another webserver.

This is the code I'm using to setup and send the request:

```
function currentStatePlaying($ip){
$url = "http://".$ip."/?track=ginfo";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
}
```

I notice that the result is empty, when looking at a networkcapture made with wireshark I can see the response I need. It's embedded inside the httppacket as Line-based text data: text/html

So my question to you is:
how can I access this data?

EDIT:
here is a screenshot of my packet:

[image]

Comment: Is the response you want inside the headers or what? Could you add the debug info from cURL (if you can see it there)?

Comment: @Jack  i have added the screenshot, i dont know how to get debug info from curl

Comment: That looks like a malformed response. Headers are terminated with two new lines but I only see one. That seems to be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from your server is not properly formed. It should be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
The content goes here
```

By having `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)` you have already enabled debug mode in cURL, but perhaps you should also have `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_STDERR, "php://output")`

Do let me know if the response can't be changed (which is pretty bad).

Comment: is anyone knows how to do that in PHP? I'm trying to access certain device information but I got the same output with Wireshark, Line Based Text

Comment: `$inputs = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $inputs; `

It will work fine